# Biblical reference that if someone is saved through someone else, that creates a "reward" or "treasure" in heaven?

Tags: soteriology, heaven, reference-request

So, I'm trying to find a passage which I believe exists somewhere in the Bible (possibly written by Paul, but maybe not), where the writer rejoices in those who have been saved through his works (teaching/preaching) and goes on to say that it will be credited to him. I have tried many combinations of phrases but I'm starting to think my memory fails me on that.

Can anyone guide me to the passage or authoritatively say that it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are rewards promised in the Bible.

> "Look, I am coming soon! My reward is with me, and I will give to each
> person according to what they have done. *(Revelation 22:12, NIV)*
>
> The one who plants and the one who waters have one purpose, and they
> will each be rewarded according to their own labor. *(1 Corinthians 3:8, NIV)*

According to Bible scholars, there are [Five Crowns in Heaven](http://so4j.com/five-crowns-rewards-in-heaven).

1. **Crown of Righteousness** - for those who wait for the Lord's appearing
2. **Incorruptible Crown** - for those who discipline themselves
3. **Crown of Life** - for martyrs
4. **Crown of Glory** - for the faithful leaders
5. **Crown of Rejoicing** - for those who win the souls

Our interest here is on the *Crown of Rejoicing*. This crown is reserved for those who win the souls to Christ.

> For what is our hope, our joy, or the crown in which we will glory in
> the presence of our Lord Jesus when he comes? Is it not you? *(1 Thessalonians 2:19, NIV)*
>
> Those who are wise will shine like the brightness of the heavens, and
> those who lead many to righteousness, like the stars for ever and
> ever. *(Daniel 12:3, NIV)*

So, if you want to receive the *Crown of Rejoicing*, start bringing people to Christ. May God bless you.

Comment: Thank you, 1 Thess. was what I was looking for, and the Daniel passage is also very nice!